# WPF: Link DataTemplate labels with collection elements' properties

Tags: c#, wpf

I find really hard to formulate my issue and there's a possibility that someone answered same (or very similar) question already, but I've been looking for an hour and can't move on with my project.

I have a class called `Book`:

```
namespace Book_Manager
{
    public enum Rank { Worse = 1, Bad, Good, Super };

    public class Book
    {
        public string title;
        public string author;
        public int pages;
        public string publisher;
        public Rank rank;
        public string description;

        public Book(string title, string author, int pages, string publisher, Rank rank, string description)
        {
            this.title = title;
            this.author = author;
            this.pages = pages;
            this.publisher = publisher;
            this.rank = rank;
            this.description = description;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my `MainWindow` class:

```
namespace Book_Manager
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Book> books;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            books = new ObservableCollection<Book>();
            myListBox.DataContext = books;

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                var bk = new Book("test", "test", 100, "test", Rank.Bad, "test");
                books.Add(bk);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I want `myListBox` to list contents of `books` collection. I already made a custom DataTemplate for `myListBox` in Window.Resources but I don't know how to pass Book fields into respective Content properties:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MmuhTemplate">
        <Grid Background="White">
            <Label Content="Something like Book.author"/>
            <Label Content="How do I do it?"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

I already declared `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Book_Manager"` in Window. What now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `DataContext`, try to set `ListBox`'s `ItemsSource` :

```
myListBox.ItemsSource = books;
```

Instead of field/member, use public properties in your model :

```
public class Book
{
    public string author { get; set; }
    ........
    ........
}
```

Then in the `<DataTemplate>` bind to corresponding property :

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MmuhTemplate">
    <Grid Background="White">
        <Label Content="{Binding author}"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding propertyName}"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Above simple binding should resolved just fine because `ListBoxItem` data context is set to corresponding item in the `ItemsSource` by default.

Comment: Works great, thanks. Though, why should I use properties instead of regular members in `Book` class? I'm going to implement XML serialization later, won't that cause any errors?